# "bool is not subscriptable" error when not indexing into a bool - Python

Tags: python, boolean

I have the following function:

```
    def in_loop(i):
        global loop_started
        if i == '[':
            loop_started = True
            return [True, 'loop starting']
        if loop_started:
            if i == ']':
                loop_started = False
                return [True, 'loop over']
            return True
       return False
```

I believe this is returning a tuple that looks like (True, 'loop over') when i is "]".
I then try to index into it with

```
for index, i in enumerate(code):
    if in_loop(i):
        loop_counter += 1
        if in_loop(i)[1] == 'loop starting':
            loop_start = index
        if in_loop(i)[1] == 'loop over':
            loops[f'loop{loop_num}'] = {'start': loop_start, 'end': index}
            loop_num += 1
```

but this raises an error

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Also, code = "+++++[-][-]".

Why is this error being raised when I'm indexing into a tuple?

Comment: What happens when `i` is not `]` too.  (`None` is returned)

Comment: @Kingsley I think that's the problem there, in fact, I also believe there's a missing piece of code that return a `boolean`

Comment: This works for me: `if in_loop(']')[1] == 'loop_over':` yet if I don't pass `']'` as `i`, i get `NoneType object is not subscriptable`

Comment: When i is not ], it does other stuff, I just didn't include that to make this easier to read

Comment: The problem is `return False` / `return True` when `i` is neither `'['` or `']'`

Comment: Instead of returning a boolean you should also return a tuple, e.g., (True, 'Loop not over') or something like that

Comment: Yeh in those cases, you are returning a single bool, but your function call expects a sequence: `in_loop(']')[1]`.

Comment: That's the problem, thanks a bunch mate! If you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it so other people can see it more easily.

Comment: @Kai036 - that exact problem was highlighted below with specific comments addressing inconsistent return format. And it was even the oldest one. If anything it should remain accepted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the characters like '+' or '-' are reached you are essentially returning boolean but are accessing `if in_loop(i)[1] == 'loop starting':` nonetheless.

You must return a consistent return type for the 2nd for-loop code to work. For ex, look at the comments below to your code:

```
def in_loop(i):
    global loop_started
    if i == '[':
        loop_started = True
        return [True, 'loop starting']
    if loop_started:
        if i == ']':
            loop_started = False
            return [True, 'loop over']
        return True  #This will have side effects and is inconsistent with your other returns of in_loop
   return False  #This will have side effects and is inconsistent with your other returns of in_loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the case only when you input something that isn't `'['` or `']'`, because it would got to the second `if` of `if loop_started:`, and default if the inner condition doesn't pass, it would just `return True`, so that is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What did you init the var `loop_started` as? (Or in another word, what value does `loop_started` have when the function have not been executed?)

If `loop_started` is `False` before the function is executed, then the function would return False directly.

A quick fix would be adding an empty string after all boolean return statements.